# What is the biggest possible value of $\frac 1a+\frac 1b$ given that $2 <\frac ab < 7$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct integers and $a + b = 10$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct integers that satisfy $2 < \frac ab < 7$. If $a + b = 10$, then what is the biggest possible value of $\frac 1a +\frac 1b$?

It's easy to show that $\frac 1a +\frac 1b=\frac {10}{ab}$ for some $a$ and $b$. Now we just need to find $ab$. However, without finding the interval solutions, how do we get $ab$ from $2 < \frac ab < 7$? Or maybe we don't need to find the value of $ab$? This is where I get stuck and I appreciate any help.

Comment: $a,b$ are positive, clearly...so why not just check the (very few) cases?  It's an integer problem so you'll have to test values in any case...

Comment: On this site, I recommend using MathJax for math expressions

Comment: You would be surprised at how few cases there are to check: there are only 2.

Comment: $a < 7b < 10,~$ when $a,b$ happen to **both** be positive.  You also have to consider **both** integers negative, or one integer positive and the other integer negative.

Comment: Assuming both $a$ and $b$ are positive, there are only two pairs of integers meeting the conditions: $(7, 3)$ and $(8, 2)$.  So just brute-force it.

Comment: As an alternative to brute force (although it's true that there are very few cases to check), consider that with the restriction $a+b=10$, the sum $1/a + 1/b$ will be smallest when $a=b$, and it increases as $a$ and $b$ diverge. With that in mind, you just need to find an extreme solution (in the sense of maximizing $a$ or $b$) that meets the criterion $2 < \frac ab < 7$. So, if you've narrowed it down to $(7,3)$ and $(8,2)$, you can see that it must be $(8,2)$. This approach would serve well for larger problems where there are too many cases to check manually.

Comment: @user2661923: If both $a$ and $b$ are negative, then they can't sum to $10$ and can be safely ignored. If one is positive and one is negative, then their ratio can't fall between $2$ and $7$, so that case too can be safely ignored. (Sorry, or were you trying to lead the OP there?)

Comment: @BrianTung I was trying to lead the OP to work the problem.  Since the problem didn't specify positive integers, the OP should be required to *consider* negative numbers.

Comment: @user2661923: Ahh OK, I misread your intention.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suggested method for solving:

First, notice that $\frac ab$ is well defined, so $b$ is nonzero.  It is positive, so $a$ is nonzero.

Second, figure out which of these can be true: 1) $a$ and $b$ are both positive 2) $a$ is positive and $b$ is negative 3) $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive 4) $a$ and $b$ are both negative

Third, for each one that can be true, substitute $b=10-a$ into the inequality, and split the inequality into two pieces: one for $2<\frac ab$ and one for $\frac ab<7$

Fourth, solve each of these pairs of inequalities, to get possible domains for $a$.

Fifth, if there aren't many possible values for $a$, go through each one to find the maximum of $\frac 1a+\frac 1b$.  If there are a lot of possible values for $a$, use the derivative of $\frac 1a+\frac 1b$, and check only values adjacent to extreme points or to the edges of each of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that $a$ and $b$ are positive, then there are only nine possible combinations with $a + b = 10$, and of these, only two also meet $2 < \frac{a}{b} < 7$:

- $a = 7, b = 3 \implies \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{10}{21} \approx 0.47619$
- $a = 8, b = 2 \implies \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{5}{8} = 0.625$

Clearly, the latter is bigger.

---

But let's consider the possibility of negative numbers.  We're given that $a + b = 10$, so let's just make the substitution $b = 10 - a$ everywhere so that there's only one variable to work with.  Then your question becomes:

> What is the biggest possible value of $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{10-a}$ given that $2 < \frac{a}{10-a} < 7$?

Obviously $a \ne 10$.

If $a < 10$, then $10 - a$ is positive, so we can multiply the inequality by it without changing the order.

$$2(10 - a) < a < 7(10 - a)$$
$$20 - 2a < a \text{ and } a < 70 - 7a$$
$$20 < 3a \text{ and } 8a < 70$$
$$a > \frac{20}{3} = 6.666... \text{ and } a < \frac{70}{8} = 8.75$$

The only *integer* values of $a$ meeting this inequality are 7 and 8, which I've already worked out above.

Alternatively, if $a > 10$, then $10 - a$ is negative, so multiplying by it flips the order.

$$2(10 - a) > a > 7(10-a)$$
$$20 - 2a > a \text{ and } a > 70 - 7a$$
$$20 > 3a \text{ and } 8a > 70$$
$$a < \frac{20}{3} = 6.666... \text{ and } a > \frac{70}{8} = 8.75$$

But this is a contradiction, so this case adds no new possible values for $a$ (or $b$).  So we still have $a \in \{ 7, 8 \}$.  And as already shown, $a = 8$ maximizes the target expression.